# Jquery button label option does not work with input type checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8

Demoed here: http://jsfiddle.net/dRtaR/2/

The label option of the Jquery UI button does not work.

My goal is to have a label on the button WITHOUT having to specify a `</label>` html tag.

Can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with this jQueryUI method. From the `.button()` overview tab:

> In addition to basic push buttons, radio buttons and checkboxes (inputs of type radio and checkbox) can be converted to buttons: Their associated label is styled to appear as the button, while the underlying input is updated on click.

When you specify button on a checkbox or radio button it hides the input and styles the associated label.

Is there any reason you can't just write out the label? If you don't have access to the html you could write it out with jQuery. See [this horrible example](http://jsfiddle.net/fnuLa/). It might give you an idea of where to look next.

Comment: It is more of just an id issue. Using label requires id's, and therefore generating unique numbering if using more than one on a page. I just thought this route would be easier than that. But as you say this is impossible... I guess i don't have a choice.

Comment: Yeah, it's not ideal I know. You could work off the input's index (since this should stay static) and then use a relational selector to populate the 'for' value. But it's all going to be more involved